# GNUplot: Is there a way I can plot data from an excel spreadsheet with gnuplot?

Tags: excel, gnuplot

I have a dataset in excel I hope to plot with gnuplot.  My first column is frequency (x axis) and the remaining columns (~700) are different data sets I would like to plot all on the same graph.  Is there a way I can convert this to a .txt or .dat file and use GNUplot?

Thank you

Edit: using a for loop did the trick.

```
plot for [col = 2:i] 'dataset.csv' using 1:col w lines
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not really a coding question. Well, use Excel to save it as CSV (comma separated values) and then plot it with gnuplot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert nor open Excel files (xls, xlsx, xlsb, etc) file with gnuplot, but you can do it with other programs, such as Python. But you can also use Excel's "save as" function and save the data as a .txt file. Consider the following data.txt example:

```
fr  d1  d2  d3
1   0   1   2
2   5   4   3
3   10  7   4
```

You can plot this with

```
p for [i=2:4] "data.txt" u 1:i t columnhead
```

Alternatively, you can move the legend to the left, and specify the plot range manually:

```
set key left; p [0:4][-1:11] for [i=2:4] "data.txt" u 1:i t columnhead
```

The command `p` abbreviated `plot`. The `u` keyword abbreviates `using`, this is followed by defining what columns you would like to plot. The `1:i` tells gnuplot to use the 1st column and the *i*th column, and *i* goes from 2 to 4 (including 2 and 4), the 1st column is the frequency column `fr`. The `t` abbreviated `title`, and gnuplot is told to use the 1st line of the cols as the header.

The output looks like this:

[image: Example output].

If you want to use a csv file, and a comma is used to separate the data, iei your data.csv looks like this:

```
fr,d1,d2,d3
1,0,1,2
2,5,4,3
3,10,7,4
```

you need to tell gnuplot to use the comma as data separator:

```
set datafile separator ","
p [0:4][-1:11] for [i=2:4] "data.csv" u 1:i t columnhead
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.  Especially remembering to use the set command